# Sharepoint Workspace 2010 Local Store Location

Tags: sharepoint-2010, synchronization, workspace

When setting up local synchronization with a Sharepoint 2010 site using Sharepoint Workspace, where are the local files stored?  More importantly, how can I change the storage location?

There is a folder-like object created under username\Workspaces, but when checking the path in the explorer address bar, it shows simply username\Workspaces, unlike other folders that show as C:\Users\username\xxxx.  Right clicking the folder only provides the option to open in new window - it can't even be deleted!  There are no options for setting storage location within the Workspace application itself.

Using an SSD system drive, I don't have the space to put all this data on C:.  Only part of my user profile has been relocated to other drives, so the default for new items is still C:.  Without a knowledge of the real path where this is stored, I can't even use junction points to redirect.

Much web searching has revealed nothing on this subject.  Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the data is stored within the users profile. I don't think taht you're able to relocated the synched database. The synchronized data isn't encrypted or password protected. So you should consider to activate profile encryption within your organization.

**In addition to the location you aren't able to activate any kind of OOB protection for the local SQL CE which is responsible for storing the synched data!**

Answer (score 1):

The default location is %localappdata%\Microsoft\Office\14.0\OfficeFileCache. 
The files in this location don't look like the actual files, and contain a lot of metadata.

Per [Microsoft KB 2020636](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2020636), you can change the location of the OfficeFileCache by adding an Expandable String Value named OfficeCacheLocation to registry subkey HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Internet with the new path. (This key is for Office 2010 only.)

Answer (score 0):

In my organization, we reviewed the option of using Workspace for making files available offline, but in the end opted for a third party [SharePoint add-on](http://harmon.ie). 

Since all of out users have Outlook and use it on daily basis, it made sense to have an Outlook sidebar available with all the users' relevant files. It also can synchronize a SharePoint library or folder and makes its items available offline using Microsoft Outlook, so we opted to use it instead of the OOB feature, which was too limited and had various security problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this and I think this will do the trick: [How to change the default location of the Office 2010 Document Cache](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2020636) (NB: I haven't actually done it myself yet).

I don't have enough "reputation" on this site to post additional links, but if you search on the following, you can find more background:

OfficeFileCache Folder Size 3-4x Larger than Actual Content (SharePoint Workspace 2010)

Sharepoint Workspace Fills Hard Drive – WTF?

Comment: can you summarize what is at the links?  Links rot which will make this answer useless in the future.